# StoreKit doesn't call paymentQueue when a transaction updates

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to do a transaction using this code:

```
  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.this.is.where.the.identifier.is"];
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

The transaction goes through fine, but `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` isn't called so there is no way of updating my application to enable the pro features. I have included the delegate protocol `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` in the header file.

Answer (score 5):

please make sure that you are adding an observer to payment queue.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

observer,/code> will be object of class in whose header file you are implementing SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol.

If you have already done that than write here so that i can assist you further.

Please read following for further detail.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//#/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW1